# issue on updating roxy for Marklogic 9.0-5

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9, roxy

I am getting error while trying to run "`ml upgrade --branch=master`" in the command line for upgrading roxy 1.7.3 to get latest version of roxy.

> ERROR: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/RKAR/AppData/Lo
>       cal/Temp/2/d20180814-3552-126w2go/CHANGELOG.mdown
>
> ERROR: ["C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1291:in `initialize'", "C:/Ru
>       by25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1291:in`open'", "C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.
>       5.0/fileutils.rb:1291:in `copy_file'", "C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.r
>       b:432:in`copy_file'", "C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:359:in `block
>       in cp'", "C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1463:in`block in fu_each_sr
>       c_dest'", "C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1477:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
>       ", "C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1461:in`fu_each_src_dest'", "C:/R
>       uby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:358:in `cp'", "C:/sample/Branch_phase2
>       /Branch_phase2/ml-services/mml-cms-app/deploy/lib/upgrader.rb:47:in`upgrade
>       _base'", "C:/sample/Branch_phase2/Branch_phase2/ml-services/mml-cms-app/
>       deploy/lib/upgrader.rb:77:in `upgrade'", "deploy/lib/ml.rb:127:in`'"]

Comment: Did you investigate the "No such file or directory" error message?

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen for your reply. No there is no such file or directory error message.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are hitting https://github.com/marklogic-community/roxy/issues/802. The workaround is to change the extension of the CHANGELOG file before running upgrade.

HTH!

Comment: Hi @grtjn, Thanks for your response. But I tried with different way using above fix #802 code but still I am getting same error which I mentioned above.  Here I would like inform you that I am using roxy  1.7.3 version.

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: def upgrade_base(tmp_dir)
      FileUtils.cp tmp_dir + '/CHANGELOG.mdown', '.'
      if File.exists?('CHANGELOG.mdown') then
        FileUtils.rm_f 'CHANGELOG.mdown'
      elsif File.exists?('CHANGELOG.md') then
        FileUtils.rm_f 'CHANGELOG.md'
      end
      if File.exists?(tmp_dir + '/CHANGELOG.mdown') then
        FileUtils.cp tmp_dir + '/CHANGELOG.mdown', '.'
      elsif File.exists?(tmp_dir + '/CHANGELOG.md') then
        FileUtils.cp tmp_dir + '/CHANGELOG.md', '.'
      end         (use code in place FileUtils.cp tmp_dir + '/CHANGELOG.mdown', '.')  Thanks

Comment: comment is a bit hard to read, but looks like you appended rather than replaced the old code..

Comment: Hi @grtjn, I am replacing whole def upgrade_base(tmp_dir) with Fixed #802: check both for CHANGELOG.md and .mdown at up/downgrade in upgrader.rb Thanks